# Load testing tools for SpringBoot Web applications

Tags: testing, web, load

Currently we use soap-ui/manual posting of xmls etc for load testing our spring boot webapplications.

Looking for any free load testing tools that others have been using and want to recommend?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific load testing or in general testing tool is the one you will "like" more by lots of personal/company needs. There are plenty of them, here is the short list of them I used:

1. [Blazemeter](http://blazemeter.com/)
2. [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
3. [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org)

I presonally spent most of load testing time in Gatling, first of all it is using scala development language and quite easy to include in your Java project via maven/gradle, secondaly apart from other benefits it have direct JDBC connection possibilty which let's you to have your test data directly in database. Lots of other pros. But one more time it is strongly my opinion and my preferences. E.g. if you are big fan of XML you will most probably like JMetter, in general Blazemter is kind of a next level of JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

I usually code the test using my current favorite language, Python in recent times. For example in python this would be some code around the requests library, and possibly some multi-process code- nothing to heavy or complex.
I find it more flexible to code myself, on average having more control over the load (there are pros and cons to using a prebuilt tool in this sense) and it usually integrates better with other code in my automation suite. 
But the answer is somewhat context dependent, is there someone with the knowledge and resource to develop a tool ? do you have to document the results or make them comparable with other systems?